# LimeSurvey API - Get survey state

Tags: limesurvey

I am wondering if there is a way to get the status of a survey through the LimeSurvey API. I know that there is the ability to activate and deactivate, but I can't seem to find anything that allows you to find the current state of the survey. There are 5 states:

1. Not active
2. Expired
3. Will expire in the future (running now)
4. Will run in future
5. Running now (no expiration date)

Active Status

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should take a look at the actual API docs: http://api.limesurvey.org/classes/remotecontrol_handle.html#method_list_surveys

`list_surveys()` would do what you request, just a sample below:

```
[{u'active': u'Y', u'startdate': None, u'expires': None, u'surveyls_title': u'test', u'sid': u'925212'}, {u'active': u'N', u'startdate': None, u'expires': u'2016-09-02 00:00:00', u'surveyls_title': u'test2', u'sid': u'655426'}]
```